# How can I get case-insensitive return from array_intersect()

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have two arrays and I need to compare that and return matched value from array1. Please refer my code below,

```
$array1 = array("a" => "Green", "Red", "Blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "grEEn", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $array1), array_map('strtolower', $array2));

print_r($result);
```

My result is,

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

But my expected result is I want get it from array1 like:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Green
    [0] => Red
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because you put all values to lowercase. Just change to [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) and use [`strcasecmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php) as callback function to compare them case-insensitive, like this:

```
$result = array_uintersect($array1, $array2, "strcasecmp");
```

output:

```
Array ( [a] => Green [0] => Red )
```